# Display two array elements in C

Tags: arrays, c

I need to show the matching "dates" element with the "values" element. I'm having trouble trying to show the two arrays' elements together. For example, I need to get the highest rainfall value to show the year and month it occurred. Same with lowest etc. I have used a for loop to find the highest and lowest values of rainfall that occurred but I am unsure on how to print the corresponding date.

I think I am on the right track but have gotten to this point and don't know what to do!

I would appreciate some help with this and maybe some tips to keep in my mind if you have any to share. P.S I'm new to stackoverflow.

[Example when executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNXfx.png)

My code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
int main()
{
    // Data Declaration
    char header[40] = "";
    int size_of_array = 768;
    int dates[768] = {0};
    float values[768] = {0};
    float sum = 0;
    float sum1 = 0;
    float avg;
    int i;
    float largest, lowest;
    FILE *input_fptr;
    
    //  Opens file
    input_fptr = fopen("rainfallupdated.csv", "r");
    if( input_fptr == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Error - could not open the file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Read in the header line from file
    fgets(header, sizeof(header), input_fptr);
    printf("%s", header);
    
    // Read 768 lines of data from the file
    for( i=0; i < size_of_array; i++)
    {
        fscanf(input_fptr, "%d,%f\n", &dates[i], &values[i]);
        printf( "%d\t %g\n", dates[i], values[i]);
    
    }
    fclose(input_fptr);
    
    // Information for the user
    printf("YearMonth , Rainfall in mm\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Example: 198702 -> February of 1987.\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\n");
    
    
    // Total rainfall
    for (i=0; i < size_of_array; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + values[i];
    }
    
    printf("Sum of all rainfall values -> %.2f mm\n", sum);
    printf("\n");
    
    // Average rainfall
    avg = sum / size_of_array;
    
    printf("Average rainfall value -> %.2f mm\n", avg);
    printf("\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("--------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\n");
    
    // Largest and Lowest rainfall values
    largest=values[0];
    for(i=0; i < size_of_array; i++)
    {
        if(values[i]>largest)
        largest=values[i];
    }
    lowest=values[0];
    
    for(i=0; i < size_of_array; i++)
    {
        if(values[i]<lowest)
        lowest=values[i];
    }
    
    printf("The highest rainfall value -> %.2f mm\n", largest);
    printf("\n");
    printf("The lowest rainfall value -> %.2f mm\n", lowest);
    printf("\n");
    
    /* for (i=0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        sum1 = sum1 + values[i];
    }
    
    printf("Total rainfall for 1958 -> %.2f mm\n", sum1); */
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `struct` to group the date and value together. That is, have a single array of structs rather than multiple arrays of individual fields.

Comment: @kaylum I have never heard of struct (new to programming haha) but I will for sure have a look into it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not post images of the text output of your program, but rather just post as text. You may want to read [ask].

Comment: As you track the highest and lowest values, you need to track the index where it occurred.  Then you can compare each new value with the highest and lowest and if need be, adjust the saved index.  When it comes to printing, you know the index for the date as well as for the data.

Comment: @Darragh Any way we could get that `rainfall` file?

Comment: @oda sure, how would I go about doing that?